# Computation in Node.Js

Tags: node.js

As we're exploring Node.js at backend using Azure Mobile App in conjunction with xamarin.forms. We're going to develop a sport mobile app that has a basic input data and at the end will have report that calculate average all games (computation). We heard that computation is not strength in node.js. What do you think about this?

Comment: What do you mean by “computation is not good”? Do you have some concrete example?

Comment: We're reading from article and watching some videos. They are mentioned about this computational is not strength in nodejs

Comment: a single request will be served by a single core and will be blocking wrt cpu. Few averages should be fine.

Comment: Thanks @hyades. But how about let say each person will record 100 games and each games migh have 20+ measurement that stored in column as numbers. Will be this computation is ok (averaging each measurement)?

Comment: @dcalliances The decision will depend on a tradeoff. If your CPU time is high like 10s with only few requests coming every hour, that core will be blocked for those 10s and new requests wont be entertained. Only in these kind of situations, you could look out for other alternatives.

Comment: @hyades Can you elaborate a bit more about this please? We are using Azure as backend.